# Several questions about xslt position()

Tags: html, css, xslt, position

I have a code

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1 or position() = 4 or position() = 7 or position() = 10">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">gallery-content gallery-content-large fadeInUpBig wow</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">gallery-content gallery-content-small fadeInLeftBig wow</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">gallery-content gallery-content-small fadeInRightBig wow</xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This crutch `<xsl:when test="position() = 1 or position() = 4 or position() = 7 or position() = 10">` works, but I would like more process automatisation. If there's any method of position() to make every 3rd element takes attributes?

Answer (score 0):

answer for my question was to simple.

```
position() = 1 or position() mod 3 = 1
```

Comment: The answer is actually even simpler: `position() mod 3 = 1` covers all your cases.

Comment: hey friend, could you tell me what is position() mod should be, to match position 2, 5, 8 etc?

Comment: Well, equally obviously `position() mod 3 = 2`. You really want to learn about this `mod` thing (and its counterpart, integer division). You will need it a lot if you want do any serious programming efficiently.